# Ansible print created hosts

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

I wrote an Ansible Playbook that creates multiple VMs. The Playbook is split in two files. Main.yaml and vars.yaml. Its creating the VMs and it seems to work nicely. Im not getting any errors so i assume it successfully added the created hosts to the Inventory. I want to check if the created hosts were added to the Inventory. How can i print/list the Hosts of the inventory? My goal is to run scripts at a later stage on the created VMs. Thanks.

```
**Main.yaml**
#########CREATING VM#########
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    http_port: 80
max_clients: 200
  vars_files:
   - vars.yaml
  tasks:
  - name: create VM
    os_server:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: present
      image: "{{ item.image }}"
      boot_from_volume: True
      security_groups: ssh
      flavor: "{{ item.flavor }}"
      key_name: mykey
      region_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'OS_REGION_NAME') }}"
      nics:
        - net-name: private
      wait: yes
    register: instances
    with_items: "{{ instance_definitions }}"
 ############################################
  - name: whait 15 seconds
    pause: seconds=15
    when: instances.changed
######DEBUG#################################
  - name: display results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ instances.results }}"
############################################
  - name: Add new VM to ansible Inventory
    add_host:
      name: "{{ item.server.name}}"
      ansible_host: "{{item.server.public_v4}}"
      ansible_user: "{{ansible_user}}"
      ansible_ssh_common_args: -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
      groups: just_created
    with_items: "{{ instances.results }}"



**vars.yaml**
---
  instance_definitions:
     - { name: Debian Jessie, image: Debian Jessie 8, flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
     - { name: Debian Stretch, image: Debian Stretch 9, flavor: c1.small, loginame: debian }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) are for.

All your hosts will be in a list:

```
groups['just_created']
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below illustrates how to create in-memory hosts and list them. The magic sauce is that `add_hosts` needs to be in a separate play.

```
---
 - name: adding host playbook
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   tasks:
   - name: add host to in-memory inventory
     add_host:
       name: awesome_host_name
       groups: in_memory

 - name: checking hosts
   hosts: in_memory
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
     - debug: var=group_names
     - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
     - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can print the the content of the inventory file using from the playbook using:

```
- debug: msg="the hosts are is {{lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/hosts') }}"
```

Alternatively, you can list the hosts from command line using:

```
ansible --list-hosts all
```

or use this command from the playbook:

```
tasks:
  - name: list hosts
command: ansible --list-hosts all
register: hosts
  - debug:
    msg: "{{hosts.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for. OP creates an in-memory inventory with `add_host` module. Your method (besides being erroneous for any case in which a particular inventory was specified in the original `ansible-playbook` call) **will not** show these hosts.